# Windows Service Startup (Timeout (30000 milliseconds))

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, windows-services

I have created a windows service Setup file for my project in vb.net,but after windows service installation when i am trying to start that windows service its throwing the following Error:

```
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. 
Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for the Test service to connect.
```

What can i do?

Comment: What code do you have in your OnStart() function?

Comment: You mist a dependency of the service in the setup and the service won't be started because its broken? Besides that its pure guessing. A logging facility in your code would be helpful. If its throws an exception while starting the service a look into the EventLog might help.

Answer (score 4):

You're limited to a 30 second startup time in a windows service. If the service doesn't start responding to ServiceControlManager calls after 30 seconds, it gets terminated.

This generally happens because you've put some long running code in your OnStart() method which doesn't complete in a timely fashion.

Try to keep the bare minimum of code in your Service Constructor & OnStart methods and then anything else if needs to do such as calling the database, loading data, IO, calling external services etc, should be done in the main application.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your service [`OnStart()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method? Are you doing any heavy-lifting there? Not throwing exceptions if something taking longer than expected?

It looks as if you trying to do stuff like this

```
class MyService
{
    public void OnStart()
    {
        //blocks here
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31));     
    }
}
```

Instead you should do something like

```
class MyService
{
    private Thread workerThread;

    public void OnStart()
    {
        workerThread = new Thread(()=>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(31));     
        })

        // doesn't block here
        workerThread.Start();
    }
}
```